# Poisson distribution with conditional

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

> The number of cars produced in a factory follow a Poisson
> distribution. The probability of **not** producing a car in an hour is
> 0.11. What's the probability of producing 3 cars in an hour, knowingly that at least one car was produced in that time period?

I guess I'm a little confused and my problem relies in the translation of the conditional. I believe that $\lambda = 1 - 0.11 = .89$ is the probability of producing a car in an hour, and being X = "number of cars produced in an hour", then I'm looking for $P(X = 3 | X \geq 1)$. But how does it correctly translate to an expression? My attempt was:

$$P(X=3 | X \geq 1) = P(X=3)\times P(X\geq 1) = \frac{.89^3e^{-.89}}{3!}\times.89$$

But I'm really unsure I got it right. How am I supposed to go for this problem?

Comment: Why would you think that the mean is $.89$?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is the expectation of $X$, what is $P(X=0)$ in terms of $\lambda$?

Comment: @lulu my thinking was: I'd like to have the probability for the production of a car in an hour. Since 0.11 is the probability of NOT producing a car in an hour, the opposite of that would be: 1-0.11 = 0.89 , right?

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the mean.  If the mean is $\lambda$, then $P(X=0)=\exp(-\lambda)$.

Comment: @bgly Have you notice the comment of lulu? Was it comprehensible for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the definition of conditional expression, $P(A | B) = P(A\wedge B)/P(B)$.

In this case that would be:

$$P(X = 3 | X \geq 1) = \frac{P(X = 3 \wedge X \geq 1)}{P(X \geq 1)}$$

Comment: So $P(X=3 \hat X \geq 1)$ would just be $P(X = 3) = \frac{.89^3e^{-.89}}{3!}$? Because I believe that's the intersection